# filtering two RDD in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to do simple filtration here my RDD are

```
rdd1 = [96,104,112]

rdd2 = [112, 30, 384, 96, 288, 352, 104, 368]
```

So the result should be the RDD which contains elements from rdd2 which are not in rdd1

So it will look like ,

```
rdd3 = [30,384,288,352,368]
```

How should we achieve this

I tried this one,

```
 rdd3 = rdd1.map(lambda r: r != r in rdd2)
```

But this is not working. How to solve this,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`subtract` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.subtract) which:

> Return each value in self that is not contained in other.

```py
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([96,104,112])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([112, 30, 384, 96, 288, 352, 104, 368])

rdd2.subtract(rdd1).collect()
## [384, 352, 368, 288, 30]
```